# Ecmascript not running in html file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I created a html file and paste it under layout folder and browse using the url `http://[server-url]/_layouts/sptest.html`. In that file I am just using a simple button. And onclick just return the number of item in pages library but it throw error `SP.PageContextInfo.get_$g_0().webServerRelativeUrl` is null or not an object in SP.js file.
Am I missing any thing? Please help!

Here is a code for that file:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="copyText()" value="Display input type" id="button1">
<script src="http://win-csmrhq8pr58/_layouts/1033/init.js"></script>
<script src="http://win-csmrhq8pr58/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script src="http://win-csmrhq8pr58/_layouts/sp.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://win-csmrhq8pr58/_layouts/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script src="http://win-csmrhq8pr58/_layouts/sp.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">    
function copyText()
{ 
  MainFunction();
  //ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(MainFunction, "sp.js");   
}
var objContext = null;   
var objWeb = null      
var objList = null;  
var objItem = null;  

function MainFunction() {     
  objContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
  objWeb = objContext.get_web();     
  objList = objWeb.get_lists().getByTitle("Documents");  
  objContext.load(objList);  
  objContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess),Function.createDelegate(this,
this.onFail));     
}     

function onSuccess(sender, args) {  
  alert('Item Count: ' + objList.get_itemCount());  
 }         
function onFail(sender, args) {     
  alert('Some error has occured.');     
 }    
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint JavaScript client object model only works on pages that are a part of the SharePoint framework (i.e. in Web Parts, Application Pages, etc.).

[See similar question here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21756/how-can-i-use-the-sharepoint-javascript-object-model-from-a-plain-html-page)