# Custom .aspx as modal dialog not working: 'SP' is undefined

Tags: 2013, javascript, modal-dialog, sp.sod

SharePoint 2013 server...

I have created a custom aspx page for use as a modal dialog.  I want this pop up to collect field values and return them to the form the pop up was called from.  The pop up opens fine, but when I click 'OK' I get.... **'SP' is undefined**.

Using a button, I am loading sp.js (as below) before calling my close and pass data function (which contains the error line above).  Is there another SharePoint library I should be loading?

```
function loadScripts(){
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(closePopupAndPassData, "SP.js");
}

function closePopupAndPassData(){
    var fakeData = "test";
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, fakeData);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: Try this ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(closePopupAndPassData, "SP.js")

Comment: 'ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded' is undefined.   :(

Comment: Because I basically used a blank aspx page through the use of SharePoint Designer 2013....I feel like I'm just missing certain SP script library references....but have no idea which others to use....???

Comment: SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () { console.log("Initiating SP.ClientContext") });
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(closePopupAndPassData,"sp.js");

Comment: 'SP' is undefined on the SP.SOD lines.

Comment: So basically I don't have a reference to anything 'SP'.   Editing my original post.

Answer (score 1):

You should add following reference to your ASPX markup

```
<Sharepoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" Name="sp.ui.dialog.js" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" runat="server"></Sharepoint:ScriptLink>   
<SharePoint:FormDigest runat="server" />
```

Comment: Added your suggestion.  Before the modal dialog opens, I'm now getting "Type is undefined" on Type.registerNamespace("SP").

Comment: Can you update the question and post the complete code in the aspx markup

Answer (score 1):

In addition to loading the sp.ui.dialog.js file, change the

`SP.SOD.executeordelayuntilscriptloaded`

to

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc ("sp.js","sp.ui.modalDialog",myfunc)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a working solution of this issue in other topic:

> This is what I used to fix this problem:
>
> ```
> <SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="MicrosoftAjax.js" runat="server" Defer="False" Localizable="false"/>
> <SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.core.js" runat="server" Defer="False" Localizable="false"/>
> <SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.js" runat="server" Defer="True" Localizable="false"/>
> ```
>
> I added the above ScriptLinks in this order, and defered both the MicrosoftAjax.js and SP.Core.js includes, and delayed the SP.js. The SP.js file has dependencies in the preceding includes that requires it to be delayed.

[How can I use the SharePoint Javascript Object Model from a plain HTML page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21756/how-can-i-use-the-sharepoint-javascript-object-model-from-a-plain-html-page)