# Getting Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Type is not defined

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, jsom, office-web-apps, office-365-developer

I am getting these errors below when i run my SharePoint Add-In (app-part):

[image]

And i define my scripts like this in my index.html:

```
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.UI.Controls.js"></script>
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="/_layouts/15/clienttemplates.js"></script>
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="/_layouts/15/clientforms.js"></script>
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="/_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="/_layouts/15/autofill.js"></script>
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.RequestExecutor.js"></script>
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
```

How can i fix this issue??

Comment: Check the answer here, You might get it...http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21756/how-can-i-use-the-sharepoint-javascript-object-model-from-a-plain-html-page

Comment: I had to put all my scripts this way, and it stop bugging me with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to put all my scripts this way, and it stop bugging me with the error.

```
   <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.core.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.runtime.j" runat="server" OnDemand="true" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="SP.UI.Controls.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clienttemplates.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientforms.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="autofill.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.RequestExecutor.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
```